# Can a YouTubePlayerFragment be used in a ViewPager? Alternatives if not?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want a small view containing 2 or 3 YouTube videos, embedded within a wider layout (tablet-only). The user should be able to tab between the videos (while remaining on the same Activity/screen). Is it possible to do this using the YouTubePlayerFragment?

So far it seems not (here's a [relevant bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7145&q=viewpager&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary#makechanges), but as it hasn't been commented on it's not yet a definitive 'no').

Using a YouTubePlayerFragment on its own works fine, but I get a sporadic variety of problems within a ViewPager (among them: unspecified connection problems with no YoutubePlayer callbacks occurring; each fragment showing the same thumbnail; blank views with no callbacks or other feedback).

Here's some code pulled out of a toy test project. I may have introduced errors editing for this post, and I've skipped configuration change handling etc for clarity:

```java
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

  private static String API_KEY = "something";

  public MainActivityFragment() {
}

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return rootView;
}


class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private String[] getVids(){
        return new String[]{"ORgucLTtTDI", "WzQ2RvSLR4o","dQw4w9WgXcQ"};
    }

    public Adapter(final FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(final int position) {
      YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
      fragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                    final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer,
                    final boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getVids()[position]);
            }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getVids().length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
        return getVids()[position] + " [" + position + "]";
    }
}
```

}

What I'd like to know is:

1. Am I doing something wrong to cause the errors?
2. If not (ie. it's a bug or limitation of YouTubePlayerFragment) is there a workaround?
3. If not (ie. I'm on a hiding to nothing with this approach), what might be an alternative worth exploring? Some I'm canvassing are:

   - some fancier use of viewpager. Eg. use a single YouTubePlayerFragment instance, putting it into the ViewPager when pages are switched, and re-cuing.
   - skip ViewPager altogether. Manually instantiate and switch YouTubePlayerFragments into a FrameLayout
   - an alternative to the YouTube player API. Perhaps a vanilla VideoView, or ExoPlayer (though its support for only API > 15 might be a roadblock)

Comment: try YoutubePlayerSupportFragment? take care of what package of Fragment you use

Comment: Yep, in the code it's a support fragment (the app leans heavily on support libraries). I just didn't type that out in the title to keep it shorter ;)

Comment: @Cris Any luck with this?  I've been wrestling with the same problem for a couple days.  The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: @Julian Can you say a bit more about what didn't work? If your original problem's the same as mine, it's worth persevering, as the answer below is in production, ie. "it worked for me" ;)

Comment: See the YouTubeSample shipped with the release. Specifically look at the VideoListDemoActivity for how it uses the YouTubeThumbnailView for each cell. That's what I'd recommend using for the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workable (if not ideal) solution. The issue seems to result from the streaming connection from the previous fragment still being open when the ViewPager slides a different fragment into place.

My solution is to call `.reset()` on the old YoutubePlayer when the ViewPager is switched, and then `.initialize()` again on the new one. This requires responding to the TabLayout's `onTabSelected` events, which means I can't use `.setupWithViewPager` (which swallows both the ViewPager and TabLayouts view change events). This is roughly what's needed in the adapter (`initialisePlayer` and `shutDownPlayer` are called in response to tab changes, in the fragment that sets up the adapter, ViewPager and TabLayout):

```java
        private SparseArray<YouTubePlayerSupportFragment> fragments = new SparseArray<>(3);
        private SparseArray<YouTubePlayer> players = new SparseArray<>(3);

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(final int position) {
            YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
            fragments.put(position, fragment);

            return fragment;
        }

        public void initialisePlayer(final int position) {
            YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
            fragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, final boolean b) {
                    players.put(position, youTubePlayer);
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getVids()[position]);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                }
            });

        }

        public void shutDownPlayer(int position) {
            YouTubePlayer player = players.get(position);
            if (player == null) {
                return;
            }
            player.release();
        }
```

Drawbacks of this approach:

- need to store refs to the YouTubePlayerSupportFragments and YouTubePlayers
- tabs reinitialise on each switch

I'm open to better solutions if any arise.